# mouse dysfunction

Tags: 13.04, mouse

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04. Each session ends with the same phenomenon. No matter what program I use on Ubuntu, at some time the mouse shows the following dysfunction: The mouse works only in the current running window. It is not possible to finish the current window with the mouse. Mousepointer can be moved, but has no further function. Cancelling with the keyboard is still possible. Error occurs with any other mouse, but the definite moment of dysfunction is not replicable. Sometimes error remains even after reboot. 
System is installed parallel to windows 7 32-bit. Ubuntu is also 32-bit.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: We need at least your PC model.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to trouble shoot this issue with such little information. Firstly i'd recommend comparing the results of `xinput list` and `lsinput` when the mouse is functioning correctly and then when the mouse has stopped functioning correctly.

xinput list - will show what input devices are recognized by xorg.

lsinput - will show your device and its capabilities ( what kind of events it can produce ). Maybe the capabilities is changing, for some strange reason which prevents mouse clicks.